# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'handler' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, sendgrid

I am trying to generate an email for forgot password in my project. But when ever i click the send password button it gives me an error:- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'handler' of undefined. Below is my code.
I am Using the html classes created by webflow in my view and also the webflow. JS script. I am getting the error:-Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'handler' of undefined in the below code of webflow.js. I want that when i click i should get the mail on my email id. I am using sendgrid for sending the email.

my Js code:-

```
 function addListeners() {
    listening = true;

    // Handle form submission for Webflow forms
    $doc.on('submit', namespace + ' form', function(evt) {
      var data = $.data(this, namespace);
      if (data.handler) {
        data.evt = evt;
        data.handler(data);
      }
    });
  }
```

My View code:-

@model InCubatize.Models.User

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = @Resources.LanguageResource.ForgotPasswordTitle;

}

<div class="w-container logo_container"><img class="login_logo" src="~/Images/images/Logo%20-%20Blue%20(V).png" width="100" alt="5488354fba4bc2be7fd98967_Logo%20-%20Blue%20(V).png">
  </div>
  <div class="w-container login_form_container">
    <div class="w-form">
    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {

      <div class="card_main login_card_nest" id="email-form" name="email-form" data-name="Email Form" data-redirect="/login">
     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { @class="w-input login_textfield", id="Reg-Email", type="email", placeholder="Email", name="Reg-Email", data_name="Reg Email", required="required" })
        <br />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)


        <input class="w-button login_button" type="submit" value="Recover my password" data-wait="Please wait...">

         @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class= "ValidationSummaryMessages" })





        <div class="login_textblock">New user?
            <a href="~/#/user/register" class="tertiary_action_btn">Create account</a>

        <span class="back_to_login">
             <a href="~/#/user/login" class="tertiary_action_btn forgot_text">Back to login</a></span>
     </div>




         </div>}
      <div class="w-form-done">
        <p>Thank you! Your submission has been received!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="w-form-fail">
        <p>Oops! Something went wrong while submitting the form :(</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/js/webflow.js"></script>
```

my HTTP Post method:-

```
  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ForgotPassword(string email)
        {
            try
            {
                User lUser = new User();

                var userQuery = from u1 in db.Users
                                where u1.Email == email
                                select u1;
                List<User> userList = userQuery.ToList();
                if (userList.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (User cu in userList)
                    {
                        if (cu.Status == (int)Enums.UserStatusType.Active)
                        {
                            string msg = HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("LanguageResource", "ForgotYourPasswordEmailBody").ToString();

                            msg = msg.Replace("[FULLNAME]", cu.FullName);

                            string decryptedPassword = Encrypt.DecryptString(cu.Password);
                            decryptedPassword = decryptedPassword.Remove(0, cu.Id.ToString().Length);
                            msg = msg.Replace("[PASSWORD]", decryptedPassword);

                            string emailFrom = Helpers.CommonFunctions.GetApplicationSettingValue("SystemEmailId");
                            Emailer.SendEmail(cu.Email, HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("LanguageResource", "ForgotYourPasswordEmailSubject").ToString(), msg, emailFrom);

                            ModelState.AddModelError("", HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("LanguageResource", "ForgotYourPasswordEmailSuccessMessage").ToString());
                            return View();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ModelState.AddModelError("", HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("LanguageResource", "InactiveUserMessage").ToString());
                            return View();
                        }
                    }
                }

                return View();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.ToString());
                return View();
            }
        }
```

Comment: It simply means `data` is undefined. This: `var data = $.data(this, namespace);` gives you undefined, are you sure the data attribute you are searching for exists?

Comment: I am not sure. how can i figure it out. please let me know. I have the same solution in which email is working.But the only difference in both solution is the View code.